# Як правильно писати - фриланс/фрилансер чи фріланс/фрілансер?

Tags: правопис, запозичені-слова, орфографія, spelling

Постійно зустрічаю як *фриланс(ер)*, так і *фріланс(ер)*, хоча *фріланс* - набагато частіше.

В українській Вікіпедії є головна стаття [Фрилансер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80) і перенаправлення з *фрілансер*. В самій статті вказано що

> Фрила́нсер, також трапляється написання фрілансер (англ. freelancer —
>   «вільний митець»)

проте нічого не вказано з приводу правильності чи помилковості вживання обох варіантів.

Інші приклади:

- Біржа Proffstore - **фріланс** Україна
- Глобал **Фріланс** - завдання з усього світу
- Що таке **фріланс** - ФРИЛАНС.com.ua - Фриланс в Украине
- Що таке **фріланс** і хто такі **фрілансери**
- beFree - **фріланс** для українців
- Що таке **фріланс**? Як заробити **фрілансом**? – Рада
- [Фрілансер](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=19335&action=show) (словник іншомовних слів)
- [Фріланс](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D4%D0%B2%CB%C0%CD%25D) (slovnyk.ua)

В українському правописі читаю в розділі "III. ПРАВОПИС СЛІВ ІНШОМОВНОГО ПОХОДЖЕННЯ":

> "И" пишеться:
>
> 1) у загальних назвах після приголосних `д`, `т`, `з`, `с`, `ц`, `ж` (`дж`), `ч`, `ш`, **`р`**
>   перед наступним приголосним: дизель, динамо, диплом, директор,
>   методика; інститут, математика, стимул, текстиль, тип; зиґзаґ,
>   позиція, фізичний; марксизм, силует, система; цистерна, цифра;
>   жирандоль, режим, джигіт, джинси; речитатив, чичероне; ширма, шифр;
>   бригада, риф, фабрика;

Відповідно, роблю висновок, що правильний варіант все ж *фрилансер*.

Як насправді?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Фриланс*** та ***фрилансер*** згідно **[правила дев'ятки](https://uk.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)**.

---

Пра́вило дев'я́тки — правописне правило української мови. У чинному правописі вимагає писати в запозичених загальних назвах після 9-ти приголосних, **д, т, з, с, ц, ж, ш, ч, р**, перед наступною літерою, що позначає приголосний звук (крім "й") літеру "и" на місці "і": с**и**гнал, д**и**намо, пр**и**нтер і т. д. — а не с**і**гнал, д**і**намо, пр**і**нтер, як у першоджерелі.

Якщо за і в іншомовному слові йде літера, що позначає голосний, то правило дев'ятки не діє. Наприклад: *діадема, діоптрій, тіофен, станція, адажіо, Чіо-чіо-сан*.

Після приголосних у кінці невідмінюваних слів також пишеться літера "і": *колі́брі, парі́, таксі́* (але *таксист*), *Віші́, Замбе́зі, Ка́прі, Кара́чі, Нагаса́кі, По́ті, Сан-Сусі́, Фі́джі; Пестало́цці*.

Також у власних іншомовних назвах може бути порушення "правила дев'ятки" - після **д, т, з, с, р** відбувається написання **і** (*Д**і**дро, Т**і**то, З**і**мбабве, Місс**і**с**і**пі, Гр**і**мм*).

Існує мнемонічне речення для полегшення запам’ятовування правила дев’ятки: **д**е **т**и **з**’ї**с**и **ц**ю **ч**а**ш**у **ж**и**р**у.

Comment: Зазначу, що в чинному правописі "правило дев’ятки" знаходиться в пункті, який розпочинається словами: "5. Залежно від позиції та вимови в українській мові і, у (ігрек) передаються також літерами і, ї та и." Тобто воно безпосередньо стосується лише передачі латинських літер i та y.

Answer (score 13):

Фрілансер — це українське написання англійського слова freelancer.

Згідно з [офіційними рекомендаціями](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626104303/http://sips.gov.ua:80/ua/transliteruvannja.html), для транслітерування англійских слів треба подивитись на транскрипційни знаки, та транслітерувати кожен знак відповідними українськими літерами.

Англійська [табличка](https://web.archive.org/web/20071026160319/http://www.sdip.gov.ua/t/docman/binary/trans/04ND41.doc):

```
№ п/п   Транскрипційні знаки   Українські літери
        англійської мови

...
14      i:                     і
...
```

Freelancer транскрибується як [`/ˈfriːlɑːnsə/`](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/freelancer).

Звук "iː" траскрибується українською літерою "і". Тож правильно писати **фрілансер**.

Comment: Як щодо правила написання слів іншомовного походження з українського правопису, що я навів?

Comment: Але ця табличка транслітерації **для власних назв** (точніше — для [«назв юридичних і фізичних осіб та їхніх адрéс»](https://web.archive.org/web/20071026160210/http://www.sdip.gov.ua/t/docman/binary/trans/03ND123.doc)), а не універсальна.

Answer (score 4):

[«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (2008) не містять ані *фриланс(ер)*, ані *фрілансер*. Зате інші українські еквіваленти англійських слів на *free…* він пише з *фри…*:

- *фри́зер* (*freezer*);
- *фриста́йл* (*freestyle*);
- *фритре́йдер* (*freetrader*).

Відповідно можна припустити, що й *freelance(r)* мало б писатися як *фр**и**ла́нсер* (тим більше, що згідно з [§ 90.5.в.1 «Правопису» 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5v1) мало б бути *…и…*) — хоча останню крапку мають поставити нові словники (що міститимуть це слово безпосередньо) і практичний ужиток.

Оновлення: [кажуть](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F:%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80&diff=22811297&oldid=19746872), що [«Новий словник іншомовних слів»](//chytayka.com.ua/novij-slovnik-inshomovnih-sliv-40-tis-sliv/id76204.html) за ред. Л. І. Шевченко (2008; ISBN 9789664980279; рекомендований Інститутом філології КНУ ім. Т. Шевченка) на с. 639 містить *фріланс* і *фрілансер*.

Answer (score 3):

[За Правописом (§90)](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5v1)

> **И** пишеться:
>
> 1) у загальних назвах після приголосних д, т, з, с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, р
>   перед наступним приголосним

[OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80/)

[image]