# "Мобільний банкІнг" чи "мобільний банкИнг"?

Tags: правопис, запозичені-слова

При перегляді статті на одному з українських ресурсів зустрів вживання словосполучення "мобільний банк**и**нг". Словосполучення як термін означає:

> Мобільний банкінг – це система, що дає можливість одержання інформації та управління коштами на банківському рахунку за допомогою мобільного телефону або планшетного комп'ютера. Перші системи мобільного банкінгу з'явилися в світі в 1999 році, коли банки Європи запропонували своїм клієнтам користуватися цією послугою за допомогою SMS-повідомлень. А ще раніше існував такий вид банкінгу, як управління платежами зі свого банківського рахунку за допомогою вказівок фахівців call-центру банку.

Джерело: [Україна фінансова](http://www.ufin.com.ua/analit_mat/gkr/160.htm)

Але завжди зустрічав в описах банківських послуг вислів "мобільний банк**і**нг".

І згідно з чинним "Українським правописом", зокрема [зазначено](http://pravopys.net/#search=90-91):

> 5. Залежно від позиції та вимови в українській мові **і**, **у** (ігрек) передаються також літерами **і**, **ї** та **и**.
>      а) **І** пишеться:
>      ...
>      `5.` В усіх інших випадках після **б, п, в, м, ф, г, к, х, л, н** перед наступним приголосним: *бі́знес, піло́т, вібра́ція, акаде́мік, фіна́нси, гра́фік, кілогра́м, **кін**о́, ...*.

Але, разом з тим, іcнує й наступна примітка:

> **Примітка 1.** У ряді слів іншомовного походження, що давно засвоєні українською мовою, після **б, п, в, м, ф, г, к, х, л, н** пишеться відповідно до вимоги **и**: *бурми́стер (але бургомі́стр), ви́мпел, єхи́дна, імби́р, кипари́с, лима́н, ми́ля, мирт, ни́рка, спирт, химе́ра та ін., а також у словах, запозичених із східних мов, переважно тюркських: башки́р, ги́ря, калми́к, кинджа́л, кирги́з, кисе́т, кишла́к*.

Яка, якщо я вірно зрозумів, до слова "*банкінг*" не застосовується, і, тому англійське слово "*banking*" в українській мові повинно мати оформлення "*банкінг*". Підкажіть, будь ласка, чи істинне моє твердження?

Comment: «Українське агентство фінансового розвитку» не є авторитетним мовознавчим джерелом, і тому цілком природно, що припускається помилок.

Comment: Перепрошую, можливо я не зовсім вірно побудував повідомлення, якщо утворилось таке враження, але вживання словосполучення "мобільний банкИнг" «Українське агентство фінансового розвитку» на сторінках свого веб ресурсу не застосовувало, то був зовсім інший інформаційний ресурс, і з певних причин, я на нього не посилався.

Comment: Але у випадку такої самоцензури запитання стає зовсім незрозумілим: *«Деяке неназване джерело послуговується правописом `X`; чому воно це робить?»* Якої обʼєктивної відповіді можна очікувати?

Comment: Перепрошую, шановний добродію, а хіба назва мого повідомлення - питання (“Мобільний банкІнг” чи “мобільний банкИнг”) не розкриває суті самого питання?

Comment: На мою думку, запитання вже містить відповідь з посиланням на поважне джерело (правопис `и` також називається [«правило девʼятки»](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/334/)). Будь-яка інша відповідь так і виглядатиме: «правильно писати — за правилом девʼятки». Якщо ж запитання про суперечність, то мають бути вказані **обидва** джерела суперечності. Одне джерело ви вказали — чинний правопис. Друге джерело — невідомий сайт, який a-priori не є поважним, допоки не названий. А коли вкажете сайт, я майже упевнений, що відповідь буде — «сайт не авторитетний і помиляється, пишемо згідно Правопису».

Comment: Перепрошую, правильно я Вас зрозумів, що зустрівши будь-де відомості які викликали в мене суперечності, я повинен **обов'язково** занотовувати джерело і чітко посилатися на нього у своєму запитанні, чи все-таки акцентувати увагу на самій суті питання?
З.І. Я не фахівець у відповідній - лінгвістичній сфері, тому я не знаю хто, як і де та якими назвами правила називає. Моє звернення - питання, щодо вірності застосування мною правила або ні.

Comment: Ні, не обовʼязково, лише бажано. Дивіться: якщо запитання «як правильно писати?» (по суті правопису), то відповідь — «користуємося чинним правописом, посилання на який надано у запитанні». Якщо запитання «чому *десь* написано інакше, ніж у правописі?» (про суперечність), то відповіді не існує, допоки ми не знаємо, де це — *«десь»*.

Answer (score 2):

По-моєму, Ваше твердження цілком правильне.

Адже ми маємо [зафіксоване в словниках слово «банкі́р»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=180073&page=109) (а не «банки́р»).

Тобто ймовірність того, що слово «банк{і/и}нг» належить до згаданої в примітці категорії («давно засвоєні українською мовою… пишеться… „и“»), доволі мала. (Воно навіть не зафіксоване в словниках — як воно може бути давно засвоєним? Навіть «банкір», що з'явилося в мові трішки раніше і проникло дещо глибше, не належить до цієї категорії.)